# javascript show dropdown menu when the previous dropdow menu has selected something

Tags: javascript, php, drop-down-menu

I am *attempting* to use javascript and I'm a beginner at it. I'm trying to get a dropdown menu added when a value has been changed from the previous dropdown menu. 
I want to show the exact same dropdown menu when the previous one has a value. So when you have 3 dropdown menu's with value's, you have 4 dropdown menu's with the same options etc.

So I use the `oninput` like this:

```
<select name="select" oninput="myFunction()">
```

and this is the function I use from w3schools:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<tr><td>
    <select name='select' id='test' oninput='myFunction()'>
     <option value='test'>test</option> 
     <option value='test'>test</option>
     </select></td></tr>";
}
```

This is the `demo` id:

```
<table><div id="demo"> </div></table>
```

but I have 2 problems with this.

1. When trying to use this, it wont work. However it does work when I use:

`document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "test"`

2. This isn't showing the same dropdown menu since I have the options of the original dropdown menu in a `for` but I cant put the `<div id="demo"> </div>` in the for loop since it will show the dropdown menu the amount of options there are.

My question(s):

Is there a way to produce the exact same dropdown menu in a javascript function?

If not, what is going wrong with the code I have.

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Sorry i copied that wrong. In my actual code, it does have the `"`

Comment: Is the table started anywhere? Your innerHTML starts with a `<tr>` but I don't see `<table>`

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Yes it is. It just keeps all the dropdown menu's in the table so the table isn't in the function itself.

Comment: might be an idea then to post actual code as we are seeing potential errors which aren't really there

Comment: @DarrenSweeney Got the table in it. Cant see any other potential errors which aren't really there.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use jQuery ajax. Put your dropdown in html (for example dropdown.html)

Then use this:

```
$("#id_of_first_dropdown").change(function(){
  $("#div_where_u_want_new_select").load("path/to/dropdown.html", function(){
      $("#div_where_u_want_new_select").fadeIn();
  });
});
```

In html:

```
<select name="...">
  <option>..</option>
</select>
<div id="div_where_u_want_new_select"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#div_where_u_want_new_select {
  display: none;
}
```

in dropdown.html

```
<select name="...">
  <option>..</option>
</select>
```

With this you can use it only once.. If you want this use unlimited so one of possible answers is change js:

```
   $("#id_of_first_dropdown").change(function(){
      $.ajax({
         url: "path/to/dropdown.html",
         success: function(data){
             $("#div_where_u_want_new_select").append(data);
             $("#div_where_u_want_new_select").fadeIn();
         }
      })
   });
```

HTML:

```
    <select name="...">
      <option>..</option>
    </select>
    <div id="div_where_u_want_new_select0"></div>
```

and dropdown.html

```
<select name="...">
  <option>..</option>
</select>
```